# DotNet NuGet push causes TLS error on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, nuget, cicd

We're facing a issue in our CI/CD pipeline to publish our package to Nuget.

Executing this command on PowerShell:

`& dotnet nuget push "*.nupkg" --api-key $env:NUGET_API_KEY --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --skip-duplicate`

Causes the following output:

```
error: Não é possível carregar o índice de serviço para a origem https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
error:   Unable to read data from the transport connection: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexao existente pelo host remoto..
error:   Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexao existente pelo host remoto.
```

We already tried execute before:
`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` 
and
 `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;`

We're using Windows Server 2012. Already changed the registry keys to use Tls12 too.

Edit:

MSFT Edge // IE

[image: msft edge // ie]

Internet Explorer Settings
[image: ie settings]

Comment: Is it related to the specific parameters of your call, and does it happen consistently? If you run `irm https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`, does that succeed?

Comment: No, it happens in any powershell call to api.nuget.org. Internet Explorer can't connect to api.nuget.org too, but MS Edge can. No, it do not succeed with `irm` too.

Comment: Error message displays something related to RC4 cipher suite. It may be possible that during TLS1.2 negociation no cipher suite match between the client and the server. Meaning that your client may have disabled a specific ciphersuite.  WireShark, or any trace (netsh trace) may be helpful. You can also enable event logging for SChannel on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL`  EventLogging 0x7. Some useful information is provided on [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/manage-ssl-protocols-in-ad-fs)

Comment: If this is Windows PowerShell (powershell.exe instead of pwsh.exe), you can try to enable Network Tracing in "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config" (back this file up first!!!) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing#configure-network-tracing - then run @mklement0's ```irm https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json``` again. This will log the low-level SSL/TLS handshake and you can see what it's doing / not doing. And don't forget to remove the Network Tracing config again afterwards!!!

Comment: You can also try ```irm https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -UseBasicParsing```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error weeks ago with the following registry keys:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
```